# How to find all the changes between two different commits in WebStorm

Tags: git, webstorm, git-diff, jetbrains-ide

Suppose I want to find the differences between two commits that none of the is the HEAD commit, how can I see them in WebStorm (or any other IDE of JetBrains)?

I know the command:

`git diff <commit1> <commit1>`

but I can't find its equivalent in JetBrains IDE. So far I can only use the IDE to find the diffs between the HEAD and any other commit.